# ¿Cuál es la forma más rápida para cargar datos masivos desde PHP a MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Un directorio llamado "clientes", dentro hay N subdirectorios cuyo nombre de directorio es un número que corresponde con el ID de un cliente, por ejemplo:

```
clientes/0001
clientes/9999
```

Dentro de cada directorio de cliente hay N ficheros, cada fichero corresponde a una tabla:

```
clientes/0001/tabla1
clientes/0001/tabla2
clientes/0001/tabla3
clientes/0001/tablaN
```

Cada fichero de tabla contiene únicamente los datos de ese cliente en esa tabla y son ficheros que hay que procesar, ya que, no tienen separación por ";" o "," sino que los datos están todos juntos y hay que separarlos por posiciones, es decir, las primeras 4 posiciones van a la columna X, las siguientes 2 posiciones van a la columna Y. (Los nombres de las columnas no están definidos en los ficheros).

Actualmente lo hago de una forma que considero, más o menos, eficiente pero tarda mucho:

```
//Por cada subdirectorio que haya en el directorio "clientes"
//Acceso al directorio
//Obtengo todos los ficheros (tablas)
//Ejecuto lo siguiente:
        $pdo->query(
            "LOAD DATA INFILE '".addslashes($nombreDelFichero)."'
             INTO TABLE ".$nombreDeLaTabla."
             (@row)
                SET
                    ID = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,22)),
                    COLUMNA2 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,23,4)),
                    COLUMNA3 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,27,3))
                ;"
        );
```

Entonces estoy haciendo un load file demasiadas veces: cantidad de ficheros * cantidad de clientes

¿Alguna forma más eficiente? ¿Agregar comas a los ficheros con PHP, cambiarle la extensión a CSV y cargarlos masivamente?

Comment: Primero hay que medir el tamaño de la bestia, para saber qué arma usar. ¿El host donde se ejecuta php es el mismo que el servidor de MySQL o están en una LAN, MAN o WAN? ¿De cuántos registros hablamos? ¿Cuánto tarda actualmente? ¿Es para una operación de una sola vez o será recurrente?

Comment: La base de datos creo que estará en un EC2 de amazon junto al script. Tarda unas 8-10 horas actualmente. Se ejecuta mensualmente.

Comment: Importante saber si será EC2 o RDS. Si tus ambientes son diametralmente distintos, lo que consigas de desempeño en desarrollo lo puedes perder en producción. ¿Cuántos archivos de cuántos registros aproximadamente?.

Comment: La base de datos en RDS, el script en EC2. Más de 100 tablas, piensa en millones de registros.

Comment: No es lo mismo 2 millones que 100 millones de registros. No vas a conseguir algo significativo desde MySQL, que ya hace muy bien su trabajo; tan solo calcula el tiempo de transferencia a 1Gbps, sólo tú sabes los números. Con php y multi-procesos/multi-hilos -incluso a nivel SO- puedes obtener mejora. Cambiar por un formato que tardará mas tiempo en leerse/interpretarse no te va a ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Si el cuello de botella lo tienes en el `INSERT`, procesa los datos desde PHP y haz un único `INSERT` con esos datos procesados:

```
<?php

$pdo->query("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes(
        id_cliente int auto_increment primary key,
        tabla varchar(31),
        dato1 varchar(4),
        dato2 varchar(2)
    );
");

$sql="
    INSERT INTO clientes (n_cliente,tabla,dato1,dato2) VALUES
";

foreach(glob('clientes/*') as $d){
    foreach(glob($d.'/*') as $t){
        $fid = fopen($t,'r');
        while($l = fgets($fid)){
            $sql.="("
                ."'".str_replace('clientes/','',$d)."',"
                ."'".str_replace($d,'',$t)."',"
                ."'".substr($l,0,4)."',"
                ."'".substr($l,3,2)."'"
                ."),";
        }
        fclose($f);
    }
}

$sql[strlen($sql)-1]=";";

$pdo->query($sql);
```

Quizá no sea tan elegante como tu solución, pero seguro que es más eficiente :)

Si los datos superan los 16 MB, siempre puedes ampliar el tamaño máximo de la query hasta 1 GB, modificando [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html); o fraccionando las queries, si llegara a ser necesario.

Comment: Estoy pensando tu solución... recuerda que dentro de la carpeta "clientes" están las subcarpetas las cuales son los nombres de las tablas (hay N), es decir "clientes" no es una tabla, sino que los nombres de las tablas son aquellas subcarpetas dentro de la carpeta "clientes"

Comment: Si los datos son tan homogéneos como indicas, mételos todos en la misma tabla y ya los separarás en producción con un `WHERE`, no crees tantas tablas diferentes.

Comment: En la pregunta indicas que tabla1, tabla2, ... tablaN son ficheros, no subcarpetas. Si ha habido un error, modifica la pregunta y modifico la respuesta

Comment: Imagina esto clientes/0001/001 esto significa "datos de la tabla 001 correspondiente al cliente 0001" pero luego habrá otro "001" pero de otro clientes, así para todos los clientes. Obviamente lo ideal sería que me pasen ficheros csv (uno por cada tabla) pero no es el caso, me los pasan de esta manera y tengo que adaptarme. ¿Generar un CSV por cada tabla? es decir, por cada tabla existente entrar a todos los clientes, procesar únicamente el fichero correspondiente a esa tabla y generar un CSV que posteriormente cargo con LOAD FILE? de esta forma habría N "LOAD FILE" donde N = número de tablas

Comment: Ok, modifico la respuesta añadiendo la tabla `clientes` que realmente es la única que necesitas. El código es compatible con lo que expones, pruébalo y verás que funciona correctamente. No te compliques generando CSVs, utiliza los ficheros tal y como te los proporcionan, que este script se encarga de todo. Si necesitas explotar esa tabla y no sabes cómo hacerlo, publica otra pregunta y te oriento